# Is delegating calls between classes bad practice?

Tags: c++

I know that delegating from one method to another in the same class is okay as it reduces code duplication, but is delegating calls to other class types considered bad practice?

For example:

Doing this is okay.

```c
 
double Point::GetDistanceFrom(const Point& point) const {
    return GetDistanceFrom(this->GetX(), this->GetY(), point.GetX(), point.GetY());
}

double Point::GetDistanceFrom(const Point& one, const Point& two) {
    return GetDistanceFrom(one.GetX(), one.GetY(), two.GetX(), two.GetY());
}

double Point::GetDistanceFrom(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return std::sqrt(GetDistanceFromSquared(x1, y1, x2, y2));
}

double Point::GetDistanceFromSquared(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    x2 -= x1;
    y2 -= y1;
    return (x2 * x2 + y2 * y2);
}
double Point::GetDistanceFromSquared(const Point& one, const Point& two) {
    return GetDistanceFromSquared(one.GetX(), one.GetY(), two.GetX(), two.GetY());
}
```

But what about this?

```c
 

double Point::GetDistanceFrom(const Line& line, bool isInfinite) const {
    if(isInfinite) return line.ptLineDist(line.GetPointOne().GetX(), line.GetPointOne().GetY(), line.GetPointTwo().GetX(), line.GetPointTwo().GetY(), this->GetX(), this->GetY());
    return line.ptSegDist(line.GetPointOne().GetX(), line.GetPointOne().GetY(), line.GetPointTwo().GetX(), line.GetPointTwo().GetY(), this->GetX(), this->GetY());
}
```

And this?

```c
 

double Line::GetDistanceFrom(const Point& point, bool isInfinite) const {
    return point.GetDistanceFrom(*this, isInfinite);
}
```

Comment: For people voting to close the question - what would you improve?  This question is a mix between a code review and asking about OO principals, but I personally think it has a concrete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is delegating calls to other class types considered bad practice?

The OO design rule that is probably most applicable is [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).  The `Point` class shouldn't really know that the `ptSegDist` method exists on `Line`.  But it is free to do anything it wants with its public interface.

In this case, it seems like you could easily swap the responsibilities you are delegating:

```
double Point::GetDistanceFrom(const Line& line, bool isInfinite) const {
    return line.GetDistanceFrom(*this, isInfinite);
}

double Line::GetDistanceFrom(const Point& point, bool isInfinite) const {
    if(isInfinite) return ptLineDist(GetPointOne().GetX(), GetPointOne().GetY(), GetPointTwo().GetX(), GetPointTwo().GetY(), point.GetX(), point.GetY());
    return ptSegDist(GetPointOne().GetX(), GetPointOne().GetY(), GetPointTwo().GetX(), GetPointTwo().GetY(), point.GetX(), point.GetY());
}
```

Calling existing getters on a class does not violate any OO or encapsulation rule.  In this case, it requires slightly less code, too.

Comment: Btw, note that I said *existing* getters :)  Often it is bad to create a getter to begin with, because it violates encapsulation.  But in this class's case, it makes sense to have getters/setters on the public interface.  Geometry is very low level, and hence should operate somewhat like a simple data structure (public access to its defining vertices, vectors, etc).

Answer (score 2):

The function that calculates distance between a line and a point is not part of neither the line nor the point. I would make it a global function. Or a static method of some Distance class. Actually, all other GetDistanceFrom functions should go there as well. Imagine you have to calculate distance between a square and a triangle. Where would that function go?

Comment: I wouldn't have to. Rectangles are made up of four points (and by proxy four line segments), and triangles are made up of three points. I'd just find the shortest distance between the four points/lines of the rectangle and the three of the triangle.

Comment: +1; I agree that it makes sense to put distance calculations in global functions, or a `Distance` class as static methods.  It isn't the only good design (his existing design is also good), but I like it.  It would take the many combinations of "shared" functions (functions that really don't belong exclusively to either object type) and put them in a single place.  It would also support overloads with swapped argument order fairly cleanly.  @Casey: It's a bigger algorithm than you might think, and definitely should go in its own function or class.

Comment: @Casey: And you'd be wrong. The distance between a point and a triangle is in general shorter than the distance to any of the bordering lines, just like the distance to a point is in general shorter than the distance to any of its vertices. And regardless of how easy it is – you still need some function to put the calculation in.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: What you said is true for *lines* but what he said is accurate for *line segments*, which is a common (if inaccurate) synonym.

Comment: @Casey, @Merlyn: maybe I understood something wrong, but at any rate it remains true that the distance between a point and a triangle is in general shorter than the distance to any of the bordering line _segments_. Just consider a point insider the triangle, this has zero distance to the triangle but finite distance to all points as well as to all line segments.